# How to tune Gurobi parameters using Pyomo

Tags: pyomo, gurobi

I know that I can use an automatic tool from Gurobi to find the best parameters for my model.
https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_tune.html

Someone knows how can run this tool using Pyomo?
I have a model coded using Pyomo and I would like to call this tune function.

Thanks

Comment: Why not dump your model in MPS format and tune it from the command-line?

Comment: Great! That worked. Thank you!
I will detail the solution below to help someone else.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Greg Glockner.

First, before calling the solver in Pyomo:
model.write("mymodel.mps")

After that, create a new .py file with this script:

```
from gurobipy import *
model = read("mymodel.mps")
model.setParam('TuneOutput', 3)
model.tune()
```

Comment: Or you could simply run grbtune from the command-line.